# Count grid points with criteria found in data in two separate xarray.DataArrays

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have the following three DataArrays each holding the correlation value at grid points across Africa (see ds1, ds2, ds3 below):
[image]
[image]
[image]

For each of the datasets (ds1, ds2, ds3), I have a corresponding dataArray (ds1_p, ds2_p, ds3_p) that contains the statistical significance p-value at each grid point. See below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

For each grid point, I would like to count the number of models (i.e. ds1, ds2, ds3) that agree on a positive/negative correlation, only if it is statistically significant (i.e. p-value<0.05). That is, for each grid point, I'd like to compare the sign of the value in ds1, ds2 and ds3 and the statistical significance of the sign in ds1_p, ds2_p, ds3_p and then count how many are statistically significant positive/negative  (to then create a plot that shows sign agreement across models). So for example, if a particular grid point has a positive correlation that is statistically significant in all three dataArrays (ds1, ds2, ds3) then I'd like that grid point to get a value of 3. I am finding it hard to compare across different datasets. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you’ve tried? The answer to the last question laid out a pretty clear plan for doing this - where are you stuck? Please show us your actual code and any tracebacks or an indication of why your current approach isn’t doing what you need. Also please post the result of `print(ds)` or even better post an example as code to make a full [mre]. This question should stand on its own without requiring cross referencing the prior one. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post significantly and tried to make it as clear as possible.